# JXMultiSplitPane going bonkers when I switch tabs

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, swingx, jxmultisplitpane

I'm using `JXMultiSplitPane` (from SwingX 1.6.2) to implement a three-pane horizontal interface. In the center pane is a `JTabbedPane` with two tabs: one with a `JTextArea` (in a `JScrollPane`, of course) used for entering Markdown code and the other a `JEditorPane` (again, in a scroll pane) for displaying a rendered HTML preview. When the user switches to the preview pane, the text in the editor is processed and displayed in the preview pane.

My problem is that if I enter text in the editor with long lines, and then switch to the preview, the center pane will expand. Sometimes it's just by a little bit, other times it'll take up more room than is actually on the screen. But if I move one of the resize handles manually, everything will snap back in place.

I've found only two ways to deal with this before it happens:

1. Manually resize one of the panes before entering any text.
2. Give the center pane a weight of 1 in the MultiSplitLayout model.

I can't use the second one since it will expand the center pane to take up almost the whole window by default.

Is there a way to fix this?

#### Update

After a little more testing, even technique (2) doesn't keep the size constant; switching between the two tabs changes the size of the center pane slightly.

I now believe that the problem is partly with the tabbed pane. The `JTextArea` and the `JEditorPane` do not have the same size and that `JTabbedPane` is resizing when I switch between them (since I'm resetting the `JEditorPane` text every time. This wouldn't be a problem except that `JXMultiSplitPane` will keep automatically resizing the center pane until the user forces a specific size by resizing manually.

So I should be able to fix the issue by making the size of the `JTabbedPane` fixed, but still able to be resized by the handle bars. Any tips on doing that?

Comment: hmm... might as well be a bug or missing feature in the splitpane. Please consider to file an issue in the swingx issue-tracker, you can simply link to this description (though a short runnable example would be great :-)

Answer (score 1):

The MultiSplitLayout is .. a LayoutManager, so you have to understand how it works (me too, not overly familiar with it myself :-)

The basic layout happens according to the component's prefSize, the weights are for distributing excess/missing space relative to the pref. By default, the dividers are "floating", that is they are positioned between the components as layouted by the basic mechanism. The moment a user touches a divider, dividers are "not-floating", comp sized to fit in-between the dividers. That's the reason for you not seeing the size-greed after moving the divider once. So one ways out is to

- setup the JXMultiSplitPane as usual, add the components and realize the frame
- fix the dividers after the manager has done its initial layout

  ```
  String layout = "(ROW " +
      "(LEAF name=selector weight=0.15)" +
      "(LEAF name=center weight=0.7)" +
      "(LEAF name=list weight=0.15)" +
  ")";

  JXMultiSpitPane pane = new JXMulitSplitPane((MultiSplitLayout.parseModel(layout))
  // add components and realize the frame  
  ...
  pane.getMultiSplitLayout().setFloatingDividers(false);
  ```

Alternatively, give more weight to the weights - force the layoutManager to use them for the layout itself (instead of only for the distribution of excess/missing space). A side-effect is that the prefSize of the comps might be set (by the layout, which is a no-no-never, but who's perfect ;-)

```
   pane.getMulitSplitLayout().setLayoutByWeights(true);
```

Not sure which way I would prefer or if/how that could be made easier in the multisplit ..